# What are the advantages of working in Pauli basis?

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

What are the advantages of working in Pauli basis $(\sigma_0, \sigma_1,\sigma_2, \sigma_3)$, in comparision to the natural basis? Here, $\sigma_0$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix, and $\sigma_i$ $i=1,2,3$, are the Paul matrices.

Comment: As opposed to what?

Comment: Say, in comparison to the natural basis.

Comment: It manifestly displays cyclic permutability, of use in technical manipulations, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you would call the 'natural' basis, but if you're looking for a basis of complex $2\times2$ matrices, the 'Pauli basis' has a bunch of advantages:

- Basis elements are Hermitean and square to one, convenient for complex conjugates and scalar products.
- The $\sigma_i$ are traceless, again convenient for scalar products and projections.
- The basis is closed under commutation and anticommutation, convenient for Lie algebra stuff. Expressions in terms of $\epsilon_{ijk}$ and $\delta_{ij}$ are simple.
- It is standard, convenient for looking up identities.